# Dispatching redux action in axiosinterceptor (Non-react component)

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

is it possible to dispatch a redux function from a javascript object that is not part of react's component?

Usually when i wish to dispatch an action , i would do the following:

I'll map the dispatch function to the component's props :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    autoCheckState: () => dispatch(actions.authCheckState()),
  }
}
```

And then i can just call the dispatch function like this:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.autoCheckState();
    this.setState({
      checking:false
      })
  }
```

However , now i wish to call the dispatch function from within my axiosinterceptor object , and they don't have "props"

Here is what i envisioned would be the way to use it , but ofcourse it does not work:

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
response => {
  return  response
},error => {

            ######## bunch of code that is not relevant ##########
            this.props.updateTokens(response.data.access,refreshToken)  #<--- how i would call it if i based it off the first example
            ######## bunch of code that is not relevant ##########
  return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {           ##<--- maping the dispatch to the 'props'
    return {
      updateTokens: () => dispatch(actions.authSuccess())
    }
  }


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(axiosInstance);
```

Ofcourse the above would give me the error that this is not defined , since its not a class . May i know the correct way of using redux in such a situation?

Comment: [you can simply pass it into global object like window and use it everywhere you want ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71380705/11404554)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of store.dispatch to dispatch an action from outside of your components or action creators

```
import store from '/path/to/store';

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
response => {
  return  response
},error => {
      store.dispatch(actions.authSuccess(response.data.access,refreshToken));
  return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your input , it is exactly what i needed!